# Missing font fallback affecting form inputs when flexbox is used

Tags: forms, css, fonts, flexbox

In searching for the best way to vertically center a div (age-old dilemma), I stumbled across an issue with missing fonts when flexbox is used.

See this CodePen for live example of what I'll describe below:
http://codepen.io/Mattaton/pen/PNzWEQ

*-- All of my testing is on Windows 7 using Chrome --*

I used flexbox to do the horizontal and vertical centering on a form. That worked fine until I realized that if a font is missing, the form inputs will run outside of their containers.

In this example, I have `'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;` for the default font-family on the `body`. (`$font-set1` in the CodePen)

That works fine, but if Open Sans is removed, `$font-set2`, Helvetica is missing on most Windows PCs and so it should fallback to Arial. Which it does, sorta.
The font face itself changes as seen in the input placeholders. The font looks like Arial, but the input sizes change to something I assume the containers didn't expect and they don't expand to compensate/contain the inputs.

Moving on to `$font-set3` where Arial is the first font and installed on Windows PCs, then the inputs look correct again.

All of this only happens when flexbox is used for centering. If I disable flexbox on `.form-wrapper` then the entire form expands to the full max-width of 800px set on `.signup-form`.

I'm not sure if this is a bug I can do nothing about or if there's something I can do to fix it. Anyone know?

Here's an image describing the problem:
[image: graphical representation]

Comment: why are you mixing flexbox and float? If you have the first, never ever use the latter inside of that.

Comment: Is that the cause of the problem or just a best-practices comment? I didn't really intend to use flexbox at all. The form div was there first and then I just centered it with flexbox after a lot of trial and error with other approaches.

Comment: definitely the second, but quite likely also the first. Flexbox makes float obsolete, and relying on float's crazy flow breaking behaviour inside flexbox content can do all kinds of weird stuff. Stick with flexbox, but rewrite it to flexbox-all-the-way and see if you still have that problem (awesome flexbox helpers: http://flexboxfroggy.com and http://flexboxdefense.com)

Comment: Cool. Working on converting the column layouts to flexbox now to see if the issue is gone. Honestly, I was a bit worried about the compatibility of flexbox across browsers (mostly IE). Not really concerned with IE8 and 9, but would like full support for IE 10 and 11. Using flexbox to vertically center a div was no big deal. If it failed it would just sit in its normal veritcal position. Not as nice looking, but not bad. Columns with flexbox get a little nastier if they break.

Comment: Okay, I updated the Pen to use flexbox inside the form. still acting weird. It does fix where it was getting cut off on the right with `$font-set2`, but you can see the margins between the inputs get more narrow when the inputs go outside the containing div.

Comment: also good news: as of January 12th 2016, [all the old IE versions have become obsolete and no longer supported by Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support)

Comment: That is good news. Too bad that doesn't stop people from using them! :-)
All in all, I still have no viable fix for this issue, though, even with Chrome, Firefox, and IE (at least on Windows - Don't have a way to test on Mac).

Comment: no but it means you're no longer on the hook for those people. "My 15+ year old operating system doesn't work with your site!" "what the actual f, go install Chrome or Firefox or something. Also get a new OS". On a constructive note, though: simplify. Make a simpler minimal example with a flex div, subdivided into the two column layout as one thing, and the button as one thing.

Comment: I don't know how much simpler I can make the Pen and still recreate the problem. I have stripped it down to bare bones now. Basically, it seems flexbox doesn't care about min-widths on the inputs. It just compresses the containing box into them and forces the inputs to push outside of the column divs. I don't follow why, though. The only bits that have any width assigned to them are the min-widths on the inputs (which should prevent the squishing) and the max-width on the `.signup-form` box. SO, by what rule is flexbox squishing the box in? What tells it do do that?

Comment: flexbox does call sizing shots, so: why do your inputs need min-width? Aren't they supposed to be a visually equal width two column layout regardless of the font? There should not be any minimal width necessary in that UI.

Comment: That makes no sense. Why does flexbox call sizing shots when there is another element doing that explicitly? If there's an element in that box dictating the min-width of the box, then why would flexbox override that? In this case, its job is simply to center whatever box is there, no matter the size. I don't want the input fields getting too narrow for people to use, so I added a min-width. There's nothing wrong with that. It's even more important when it collapses to 1 column in the responsive design. Guess I'll have to put the min-width on the outer box and handle change with media queries.

Comment: this is best explained by not-me: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox has all the details (the gist is that your flex-managed elements act as cells. You can always use a div as cell and then put a min-width element *in* that, but it's far better to set up your flexbox such that your content flex grows/shrinks correctly. You can set grow/shrink to "off" and then your elements need to call their own sizing shots, but you amost never *actually* need that)

Comment: Gotcha. I just put the min-width on the outer box, and only when I need it, at sub-500px screen widths when flexbox is not being used. That solves the issue. There is still, though, the original problem of why the missing Helvetica to Arial fallback produces different widths. If Helvetica is missing, both condition 2 and 3 should look identical since Arial should be used in both cases.

Comment: hmm, one thing that might be responsible here is using `font-size` with "em" values, which are font-dependent. It's generally safer to use "rem" (which is em based on the font used by the `<body>` element) since that's usually stable even when a child element's font-family changes.

Comment: Agreed, I should definitely change to rem, but still, shouldn't the browser ignore anything having to do with the missing Helvetica and completely use Arial as if Helvetica was never listed? I thought that was the whole point of font stacks.

Comment: Hm, in your updated codepen I don't see any differences on a windows machine whether I set all the font families to "Helvetica, Arial" or just "Arial" anymore?

Comment: Yeah, the min-width on the inputs made that stand out. If you uncomment the min-width on the inputs, you'll see that going from font-set2 to font-set3 makes the inputs change size. To me, it shouldn't do that if it's falling back properly (whether the min-width is necessary or not). Now, all of this is on a Windows machine with Helvetica missing. Not sure what your environment is like.